# JavaScript - SVG Text returns 'undefinded'

Tags: javascript, svg

I tried to create a text node in SVG and change it's color
however, it keeps returning 'undefinded'

```
const shp = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/200/svg","text");
const textNode = document.createTextNode(this.data["ctx"]);
const shp.appendChild(textNode);

shp.style.fill = 'red';
```

Here's my result :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fill' of undefined
```

Did I code wrong?

Comment: `const shp.appendChild(textNode);` This will throw an error. I assume the `const` keyword should not be there?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier oh I coded wrong... but that it still returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fill' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is with your namespace, you have `200` instead of `2000`, like so: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. You can see [a working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/y2m3bf5z/).

*PS. `undefined` is misspelt in your questions title*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and spelling check! It worked properly :)

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, do you mind marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: oh I forgot. I started using stackoverflow recently sorry